# Is there any possible way to bind End-User-Id using langchain_openai?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I've found a OpenAI documentation to add End-user-Ids in this documentation(https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/safety-best-practices).

I would like to know how to bind the user id using `langchain_openai` package.

```py
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

model = ChatOpenAI(temperature=1.0, model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview")
```